# Can a vehicle make a reflex save to avoid damage from Autofire?

Tags: d20-modern, vehicles, saving-throw

In d20 Modern, if a character is in a square hit by autofire, he can make a DC 15 Reflex save to avoid taking damage.

I can't see anything in the SRD about what happens to a vehicle hit by autofire. My gut says that since vehicle stats don't include a Reflex save modifier, they cannot avoid taking damage from Autofire (if the attacker hits with his attack). Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, because a manned vehicle fits the definition of an "attended object" - "An object attended by a character (being grasped, touched, or worn) receives a saving throw just as if the character herself were making the saving throw."  So if there's someone driving, it gets the driver's saves.  (If no one's driving, it gets no save.)

You could certainly decide to apply the vehicle's Maneuverability to this roll - in fact, it's not RAW, but I'd be tempted to replace the Reflex save with a Drive check, forcing decisions like "do I try to dodge and run the risk of losing control, or just bull through it".

Comment: I like your Drive check idea, however I'm not sure I agree with you that a vehicle fits the definition of an attended object. Mainly because a vehicle provides cover for the occupants. Thus it's got less in common with an item, and more in common with a piece of scenery. On the other hand: Tower Shield! I'm undecided...

Comment: Follow up question: if the driver makes his Drive check and the vehicle saves vs Autofire, would the occupants also be exempt from the effects of Autofire? Tricky, ain't it?

Comment: Yes, the occupants would be exempt, and no, it's not tricky...  Frankly it compensates for the ridiculousness that people in the vehicle are exposed to autofire regardless of the hardness/hp of the vehicle (people in a tank are technically exposed per the rules).  So short of using Spycraft instead as its rules are much better constructed, I'd allow Reflex saves for the vehicle.

Comment: Does auto fire ignore bonuses from cover? AFAIK a tank gives 100% cover.

Comment: @mxyzplk, your interpretation is correct! There's a Bullet Points article on the WotC site that answers this exact question and the WotC staffer says the vehicle is, in fact, an attended object (http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20modern/bp/20040217a). I'm going to accept your answer now. Thanks for that.

Comment: @cr0m cool, the power of my logic prevails again!  Mmmwah hah haaaaa...

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played a d20 modern session, but it would make sense to me that in most cases it would not get a save.  But I can see how a GM might make an allowance to have a driver make a reflex save if they're driving and vehicle is in motion when the autofire occurs.  But I don't think there's a rule about it.

Comment: There is a rule regarding unattended objects and saving throws. The question seems to be whether a vehicle is or isn't attended. So far I think it's unattended and mxyzplk thinks it is attended. Break the impasse!

Answer (score 1):

Hey, a little digging in the d20 Modern SRD and I found the answer! Hat tip to mxyzplk for brining up attended objects. That led me to look up attended objects and... voila!

> An object being held, carried, or worn has a Defense equal to the above figure + 5 + the opponent’s Dexterity modifier + the opponent’s class bonus to Defense. Striking a held, carried, or worn object provokes an attack of opportunity from the character who holds it.

And a little further down on the page:

> Saving Throws: Unattended objects never make saving throws. They are considered to have failed their saving throws. An object attended by a character (being grasped, touched, or worn) receives a saving throw just as if the character herself were making the saving throw.

In my opinion, a vehicle doesn't qualify as an attended object. It's neither held, carried nor worn. It's an unattended object.

So the answer: if you attack a vehicle with Autofire and hit with your attack (vs Defense 10) the vehicle takes the damage, no save.

I'd probably give the 10x10 area a speed bonus to its Defense though, since you're actually trying to hit a moving 10x10 area that overlaps with the car.

Comment: "held, carried, or worn" isn't the verbiage in the actual d20 modern book...

Comment: What is the language in the actual book? I'm still tracking down a copy.